# Python: understanding function order

Tags: python, json, function, google-maps-api-3

I usually write shameful **bad code** but this time I changed my mind and I wanted to understand Python functions.

So I'm trying to rewrite some script from the past. I don't understand why this code doesn't execute:

```
import requests                                                             # 
import json

def Status_OK():        
    for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
        SQL_Place_ID = SQL_element['place_id']

def get_place_for_show():                                                                                   
    url1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=movie_theater&location=-36.86667,174.76667&radius=25000&key=MyGoogleKey'                                                                     
    response1 = requests.get(url = url1)                                                            
    response_data1 = response1.json()

    if response_data1['status'] == 'OK':
        Status_OK()

get_place_for_show()
```

my HAL9000 reply this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 16, in <module>
    get_place_for_show()
  File "Test.py", line 14, in get_place_for_show
    Status_OK()
  File "Test.py", line 5, in Status_OK
    for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
NameError: name 'response_data1' is not defined
```

What? **NameError: name 'response_data1' is not defined?**

Is defined one line above!

The code should just print a list of the Google Place_ID and I know this code works because I'm using it on another script but without functions

Comment: `response_data1` is a local variable inside `get_place_for_show()`. It's not available in `Status_OK()`. You need to pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: You need to learn about variable scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is a **local** variable of the function. If you want to use it in multiple functions, either pass it on a function call or define it on a **broader scope.**

You can see what variables are available in your function

```
>>> get_place_for_show.__code__.co_varnames
('url1', 'response1', 'response_data1')
```

Now let's see what it looks like in the Status_OK function

```
>>> Status_OK.__code__.co_varnames
('SQL_element', 'SQL_Place_ID')
```

That's why you get the **NameError** exception; the function doesn't have that attribute (param, arg, local). To fix it:

```
import requests                                                             # 
import json

response_data1 = {}

def Status_OK():        
    for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
        SQL_Place_ID = SQL_element['place_id']

def get_place_for_show():                                                                                   
    url1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=movie_theater&location=-36.86667,174.76667&radius=25000&key=MyGoogleKey'                                                                     
    response1 = requests.get(url = url1)                                                            
    response_data1 = response1.json()

    if response_data1['status'] == 'OK':
        Status_OK()

get_place_for_show()
```

Comment: The script worked with a bit of yours and @hspandher code. Thank you so much for teaching me something totally new

Answer (score 1):

`response_data1` is a local variable inside the function `get_place_for_show`. Just because you have called `Status_OK` inside it doesn't mean it would (or should) share the scope of `get_place_for_show`. Try reading about [scopes in Python](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html).

Now if you were expecting some `closure` like behaviour, you need to define the other function inside the first one.

```
def get_place_for_show():
    ...
    response_data1 = response1.json()

    def Status_OK():        
        for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
            SQL_Place_ID = SQL_element['place_id']

    Status_OK()
    # Now it won't at least raise an error.
    ...
```

With that said, it is just for demonstration purposes, I don't see any use case of instantiating a `closure` here.

Comment: The script worked with a bit of yours and @Vinny code. Thank you so much for teaching me something totally new

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Glad, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

***A little theory about a standard issue variable's duty cycle***:
A var, when it's created in a function, gets ***DESTROYED*** after the last statement in the function is executed. You need to ***PASS*** the value of the var to the function, this way:

```
def Status_OK(response_data1):        
    for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
        SQL_Place_ID = SQL_element['place_id']
```

and call this way:

```
Status_OK(somevar)
```

Your full working code is:

```
import requests, json

def Status_OK(response_data1):        
    for SQL_element in response_data1['results']:
        SQL_Place_ID = SQL_element['place_id']

def get_place_for_show():                                                                                   
    url1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?types=movie_theater&location=-36.86667,174.76667&radius=25000&key=MyGoogleKey'                                                                     
    response1 = requests.get(url = url1)                                                            
    response_data1 = response1.json()

    if response_data['status'] == 'OK':
        Status_OK(response_data1)

get_place_for_show()
```